# Searching a MongoDB collection from the end (c#)

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I am looking for the most efficient way to get the last elements of a fairly large (> 1 million docs) MongoDB collection.

Specifically, it is the oplog collection and I am looking for all entries after a given timestamp. It makes no sense to search the first million or so entries for a timestamp larger than the current one, since they are all definitely older because the collection is stored in its natural order.

Is there a way to tell MongoDB to search from the end of a collection?
I tried a linq query with Skip(N) but it's very slow. It seems it parses through all documents from the beginning and just doesn't return the first N.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is probably using [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/). If your collection is sorted, you can get the last Timestamp using this aggregation:

```
      var group = new BsonDocument
        {
            {
            "$group", new BsonDocument
               {
                    {"_id", 0},
                    {"newestTimeStamp", new BsonDocument { {"$last","$timeStamp"} } }

               }
            }
        };
        var pipeline = new[] {group};
        var result = _dtCollection.Aggregate(pipeline);
    }
```

Then you can deserialize the result into a Timestamp class. If you want to get several elements, you could create a similar expression using $match.

Also make sure to add an index to the collection on the TimeStamp field. This will probably make your LINQ-query faster if you decide to use that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Nakata. I tried an aggregate with $match and in this particular case it has no speed improvements over a regular find.

Comment: Have you also tried adding indices to your collection?

Comment: MongoDB does not allow adding indexes to oplog.

Comment: I see. Then you could try using a find query with the SetSkip method for skipping N documents, for example : "collection.Find(query).SetSkip(100)". I'm not sure what the LINQ-equivalent syntax is.

Comment: Yes, I tried the SetSkip method on a cursor. Very slow. I also tried a tailable cursor (since oplog is a capped collection), which (quite surprisingly) didn't provide any speed improvements either. Checking if the enumerator (MongoCursorEnumerator) returns true on a MoveNext takes roughly the same time as a find. (I have upvoted your answer because of your continuing effort to help).